# Jackson: Enable Fail On Empty Beans for individual class

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am deserializing JSON in a Java application using Jackson.  Globally the application is set with FAIL_ON_EMPTY beans disabled and a central mapper is used (auto wired using spring).  I would like to override the deserialization feature that for a certain class, so that the deserialization will fail if a bean is missing from the JSON.

This question asks a similar question (but I'm looking to enable rather than disable, and want to apply the change to an individual class preferably using an annotation):

[jackson disable fail_on_empty_beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261456/jackson-disable-fail-on-empty-beans)

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=true to application.properties