# Getting 500 Internal Server Error SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I made some APIs using SpringBoot and for one of the API I am getting Internal Server Error.
For GET : `vehicles/{vehicleId}`, I am getting 500 in response. But others APIs are working fine.
I am not able to find, what is causing that error.

Controller Class

```
package com.test.vehiclemanagement.controller;

import com.test.vehiclemanagement.model.Vehicle;
import com.test.vehiclemanagement.service.VehicleService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class VehicleController {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    //get the vehicles
    @GetMapping("/vehicles")
    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles(){

        return this.vehicleService.getVehicles();
    }



    @GetMapping("vehicles/{vehicleId}")
    public Vehicle getVehicle(@PathVariable String vehicleId){

        return this.vehicleService.getVehicle(Long.parseLong(vehicleId));
    }

    @PostMapping("/vehicles")
    public Vehicle addVehicle(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle){
        return this.vehicleService.addVehicle(vehicle);

    }

    @PutMapping("/vehicles")
    public Vehicle updateVehicle(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle){

        return this.vehicleService.updateVehicle(vehicle);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("vehicles/{vehicleId}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteVehicle(@PathVariable String vehicleId){
        try{
            this.vehicleService.deleteVehicle(Long.parseLong(vehicleId));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Service Class:

```
package com.test.vehiclemanagement.service;

import com.test.vehiclemanagement.model.Vehicle;

import java.util.List;

public interface VehicleService {
    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles();
    public Vehicle getVehicle(long vehicleId);
    public Vehicle addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);
    public Vehicle updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);
    public void deleteVehicle(long parseLong);
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
package com.test.vehiclemanagement.service;

import com.test.vehiclemanagement.model.Vehicle;
import com.test.vehiclemanagement.repository.VehicleRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService{

    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository vr;


    public VehicleServiceImpl(){

    }

    @Override
    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
        return vr.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle getVehicle(long vehicleId){
        return vr.getOne(vehicleId);
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
           vr.save(vehicle);
          return vehicle;

    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){

              vr.save(vehicle);
              return vehicle;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteVehicle(long parseLong){

        Vehicle entity = vr.getOne(parseLong);
        vr.delete(entity);
    }
}
```

[image]

I am new into springboot, and I am not able to know what is causing this problem.Can someone please help me with this.

Getting the following in debug logs:

```
ERROR 224 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.cognizant.vehiclemanagement.model.Vehicle$HibernateProxy$cbnZzhbz["hibernateLazyInitializer"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.cognizant.vehiclemanagement.model.Vehicle$HibernateProxy$cbnZzhbz["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1300) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:46) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:29) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1518) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1007) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.2.1.jar:2.13.2.1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:456) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.62.jar:9.0.62]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: You need to look at the logging output from your spring boot process and find the exception stack trace. Please add it to your question, if you still need help.

Comment: @tgdavies updated the question with debug log, But I am not able to find what is causing this

Comment: Try to change `.getOne(vehicleId);` to `.findById(vehicleId).get()`. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656517/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-bytebuddy-bytebuddyinterc

Comment: this solution should be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650126/5919568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Spring Data JPA `getOne(id)` method is deprecated, try changing `vr.getOne(vehicleId)` to `vr.findById(vehicleId).get()`. This will run the SELECT query and returns the respective data of the vehicle as the `Vehicle` class object.

***Take a look at these:***

***Difference between getOne() vs findById()***

https://www.javacodemonk.com/difference-between-getone-and-findbyid-in-spring-data-jpa-3a96c3ff

***Spring Data JPA Deprecated List:***
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.5.2/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Then you just skipped the interest of using `Optional`